# Current date into environment variable in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services

My task is to make a header with the current deploy date.
I couldn't get data from AWS, so I decided to set the build date in the environment variable during the build.

For this, I created a file `.env` and put some test variables. It works, but it is constant. How can I get the current date in the `.env` file?

```
REACT_APP_VAR1=123
REACT_APP_VAR2=dddd
REACT_APP_BUILD_TIME=(What should I write here?)
```

Comment: which bundler do you use to build your app? webpack?

Comment: "it is constant" - that's generally how `env` files are, and I wouldn't expect an app build time to be dynamic either, it's a point in time. What's the real question here, how do you _write_ to the `env` file during build? If so then there's really not enough information here to answer that.

Comment: @AndriiGolubenko yes, use webpack

Answer (score 1):

Use webpack [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin) for this purpose.

In webpack config:

```
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            BREACT_APP_BUILD_TIME: JSON.stringify(new Date().getTime()),
        })
    ]
```

In your app:

```
const buildTime = new Date(+BREACT_APP_BUILD_TIME);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was getting error as I missed out JSON.stringify.